# Code duplication or not?

Tags: linq, oop

Here is another question about class design and code duplication.

This is the scenario: 
we have a class having a property called SupportedFlow. 
This property is read only and return a list of FlowInfo object, each one representing a flow (physical file sending by an external system) with a few attributes such as FlowType (an object representing the kind of flow, for instance "customer flow" or "dossier flow").

Some other classes in the system we are building need to know the list of "supported flow type" and they can get it by reading the property SupportedFlow of above object and applying a simple LINQ query: SupportedFlow.Select(p => p.FlowType).ToList()

Some other classes could need a similar list, obtained by applying a filter on SupportedFlow list by means of LINQ to object extension method Where, for istance the list of supported flows matching  any criteria (example: customer - related supported flows).

Here is my question: in such a scenario what is the best design choice, adding new properties to the original object (such as SupportedFlowType or CustomerRelatedSupportedFlows) which apply the proper LINQ query to the original property SupportedFlow, or repeating the LINQ query every time when needed in other classes of the system ?

In a certain sense I guess this is an example of code dupplication, but at the same time I'm not sure that complicating the original object by adding new properties it the best option considering that these LINQ queries are quite simple and new properties won't add clarity to code base.

Thanks for replying.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the functionality could indeed complicate the original object, but it is still better than repeating the functionality everywhere you need it.

However, there is a third option: Put the method in a util class. This keeps the original object simple and prevents code duplication. The only disadvantage is that you would need to "know" there is such a util class/method if you need it.

Comment: Thanks for replying. So, you suggest to create a Util class containing some methods such as "GetSupportedFlowType" or "GetCustomerRelatedSupportedFlows" wich takes the list of FlowInfo object as parameters and return the list obtained by applying LINQ to object query. It sounds as a good trade off !

Comment: @EnricoMassone yes, unless you can implement 1 single function that can do everything based on a parameter passed to it. I'm not familiar enough with linq or with your source code to know if that is possible